# Getting “System error 8646 has occurred.” when trying to change a user password as an administrator in Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, user-accounts

I'm trying to change my password via the command prompt on Windows 10. I'm not on a guest an  account or anything mind you, I am the main user. Anyway, I load up cmd as an Administrator and try to change the password from there:

net user {username went here} {new password when here}

And I got this error:

> System error 8646 has occurred.
>
> The system is not authoritative for the specified account and therefore cannot complete the operation. Please retry the operation using the provider associated with this account. If this is an online provider please use the provider's online site.

Even though I'm the administrator. I should stress how important it is that I’m able to change the password from the command line. I'm aware of how to do it in the GUI and have done so succesfully multiple times. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check https://appuals.com/system-error-8646-when-resetting-microsoft-account-password/

Comment: Windows is a GUI first, console second operating system.  Use the GUI.  Microsoft tests that more than the console.